# Reset password in Multiple DB Connection in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Reset password in Multiple DB Connection in Laravel.

rest password from first db connection Laravel. How to add connection name there:

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Thanks I have Found the Solution Just add the DB Connection name **

```
 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'connection' => 'mysql',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```